# (Jenkins) Run function of shared library on load

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In Jenkins, I want to automatically run a function *on load* of the shared library, which is loaded implicitally on a global level. This would allow me to enforce certain functions in every pipeline.

This means, a user would not have to define anything in the pipeline script itself to have it run.

What I tried:

```
//src/org/test/Always.groovy
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
package org.test


class Always implements Serializable {
    Always() {
        println "Always print me"
    }
}
Always()
```

This does not appear to do anything, however. I would expect it to always instantiate the Always class and print "Always print me".

Answer (score 2):

An [global-pre-script-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/global-pre-script-plugin) exists that seems to [fit your use case](https://github.com/jenkinsci/global-pre-script-plugin#use-cases). It can execute a groovy script before each job / build starts. I am **not** sure if the script can load shared libraries and inject methods (maybe as Closure variable?) from it. This is something we would need to test :)

**The plugin's last commit is from March 2020 though, so looks rather unmaintained to me.**

> This plugin makes it possible to execute a groovy script at the start
> of every job
>
> Features:

- Applies to all jobs/builds run in the server
- Executes a groovy script when a build starts Injects any number of variables in the build
- Injects properties based on the content of another property
- Executes a script when the build starts
- Very light plugin
- Failures in the script do not abort the build

Comment: Thank you! Sadly this does not work with pipelines